# can't find the function subtable

Tags: r

I'm learning R using the book, The Art of R Programming. And in chapter 6, the author Matloff used a function called `subtable <- function(tbl,subnames)`, but as I typed this function `subtable`, it says not find the function, and I googled, find it's in the package `extracat`, so I installed this package, but as I'm loading this package, `library(extracat)`, an error message came out, saying

```
library(extracat)
   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
   there is no package called ‘plyr’
   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘extracat’
```

I can't understand this, how should I use this function? Any suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: this seems to mean that you need to install the plyr package in order to use the extracat package. So just write ```install.packages("plyr")``` and then run: ```library("extracat")```

Answer (score 8):

If the book has something like this

```
subtable <- function(tbl,subnames)
```

the author is **defining a new function** called `subtable`, that receives two parameters called `tbl` and `subnames`. The code right below that is what the function runs. I found [here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/145/Handouts/R2/subtable.R) and [here](http://books.google.es/books?id=4jL3sfmP1l8C&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&source=bl&ots=0SnjDZtHDy&sig=qwkIVfaLTQd4s9dCzZmqgcfAPB4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mG-7UteGA8-10QXKnoHgCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) the function you seem to refer to:

```
subtable <- function(tbl,subnames) {
   # get array of cell counts in tbl
   tblarray <- unclass(tbl)  
   # we'll get the subarray of cell counts corresponding to subnames by
   # calling do.call() on the "[" function; we need to build up a list
   # of arguments first
   dcargs <- list(tblarray)  
   ndims <- length(subnames)  # number of dimensions 
   for (i in 1:ndims) {
      dcargs[[i+1]] <- subnames[[i]]
   }  
   subarray <- do.call("[",dcargs)  
   # now we'll build the new table, consisting of the subarray, the
   # numbers of levels in each dimension, and the dimnames() value, plus
   # the "table" class attribute
   dims <- lapply(subnames,length) 
   subtbl <- array(subarray,dims,dimnames=subnames)
   class(subtbl) <- "table"
   return(subtbl)
}
```

Once you write (or copy-paste) all that code in your R console, you'll be able to call this function. So I doubt you want to install any new packages here!

Comment: INDEED, oh, thanks very much. I was searching all over the rseek.org, and google, trying to find the package. You got me out of this, much appreciated. Merry Christmas.